# why does this HTML div have extra space below but not above

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out where this space is coming from. As you can see from this fiddle there is some white space between the `<header>` and the `<main>` section. It also appears that the space is being added on the main section at the bottom but not at the top of either one.

http://jsfiddle.net/bbor6s3j/

html:

```
<header>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Campania_banner_View_from_Capri.jpg">
</header>
<main>
   Main Section
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because img tags are inline by default and that space is for descenders (the part below the baseline in characters 'p', 'q' etc.).

You can fix this by changing the img to a block:

```
header img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: to further illustrate this point, if you set `line-height: 0;` to the header you'll see the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I didnt realize it was by default inline. That would explain it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Just change CSS OF header

```
header
{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

[image]

AS you Can See

Answer (score 0):

The space from underneath of image,
to avoid this space you need to add `display:block` or `float:left` in `header img` or
set the `height` of both `<header>` and the `<img>`.,

```
header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
header img{
    width:100%;
   height:100%;
}
```

or

```
header img{
    width:100%;
    display:block;/*added*/
}
```

or

```
header img{
    width:100%;
    float:left;/*added*/
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbor6s3j/2/%22jsfiddle%22)

Answer (score 0):

see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbor6s3j/4/)

you can set the *height* of header equal to *height* of img..

```
header{
   width:100%;
   height: 112px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple....
just use `display:block;` to image

http://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/drmsLp17/

Answer (score -1):

You can assign a negative value to padding-bottom to handle that..

Comment: I don't understand the reason for down vote.. This works.. The other solutions can be better but why down vote something else which works too..?